# Cordova 3.0.0 ActionSheet plugin for ios not working properly

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I have installed cordova 3.0.0 version for ios recently and trying to create ActionSheet plugin for ios.

Now, My problem is when tap on button nothing happens means Actionsheet does not open.

It works fine in simulator but in device

when i double press home button then only actionsheet displays. it is working fine in cordova 2.9.0.

I have also checked Datepicker plugin in this the same issue happens.

my code is given below:

```
    var actionSheet = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/actionsheet");
    var options = {
    title: 'MyTestApp',
    items: ['Open gallery','Cancel']
    };

    options.visibility = "auto";
    options.onDismiss  = openActionsheet;

    actionSheet.show(options);
```

Please help me with that....

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution.

Place .h and .m file in Plugins folder. Now create plugins folder in www and ActionSheet.js file in that www/plugins/ActionSheet.js folder.

Add below line to Config.xml

```
<feature name="ActionSheet">
    <param name="ios-package" value="ActionSheet" />
</feature>
```

Now you have config_plugin.js file in your www folder place below code in this file:

```
 {
     "file": "plugins/ActionSheet.js",
     "id": "ActionSheet",
     "clobbers": [
              "actionSheet"
                 ]
 }
```

now you can call actionsheet method as below:

```
    var options = {
    title: 'Blownaway',
    items: ['Open gallery','Cancel']
    };


    actionSheet.show(options);
```

No need to include ActionSheet.js in Script tag in html file for ActionSheet.js.

You can directly call actionSheet.show method.